C# play video in full screen mode automatically
I have a simple form that should start an mp4 soundless video in fullscreen, unfortunately I haven't be able to do that. My form consists of an axWindowsMediaPlayer control and a button when clicked video plays in full screen, I just needed that when I start the form the video  starts in full screen without need to click the button. Thank you for some hints.
This is my code:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AxWMPLib;
using WMPLib;
using static System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement.TrackBar;

namespace Ethen
{
    public partial class FrmAzkar : Form
    {
        private int Tiks;

        public FrmAzkar()
        {
           InitializeComponent();
           axWindowsMediaPlayer1.uiMode = "none";            
           TmrAzkar.Start();
        }

        private void FrmAzkar_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string path_to_video_file = "C:\\Mawakit-Al-Salat\\azkarFajr.mp4";

            if (File.Exists(path_to_video_file))
            {
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = path_to_video_file;
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File not Found");
            }
        }

        private void TmrAzkar_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Tiks++;
            this.Text = Tiks.ToString();

            if (Tiks == 540)
            {
                this.Text = "Done";
                TmrAzkar.Stop();
                this.Close();
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (axWindowsMediaPlayer1.playState == WMPPlayState.wmppsPlaying)
            {
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.fullScreen = true;
            }
        }
    }
}


Try putting your axWindowsMediaPlayer1.fullScreen = true; code into the Shown() event of the Form?

Or you could attempt to make it fullscreen

I tried  adding into form_load axWindowsMediaPlayer1.FullScreen = true; but always giving error: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
HResult=0x8000FFFF

Well, the Load() event occurs BEFORE the form (and the player) have been displayed. This is why I suggested the Shown() event of the form, which occurs AFTER the form has been displayed. This should guarantee that the player control has already been created.

sound logic but could not figure out how to use the Shown, any hint?

What? How did you use the Load() event then?! Open up your "FrmAzkar" form in design mode. Select the form itself. Then in the Properties pane (bottom right of your screen by default), switch to the Events by clicking on the "Lightning Bolt" icon. Scroll down until you find the Shown() event entry and then double click on it to get the method stub where you can add the fullscreen code.

I did that and stil getting same error: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8000FFFF):

I had to do it from the StatusChange() event of the Media Player control.
Select the Media Player control (axWindowsMediaPlayer1), then switch to the events for it in the properties pane. Find the "StatusChange" event and double click it.
Now switch to fullscreen mode from there:
private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_StatusChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (axWindowsMediaPlayer1.playState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsPlaying)
    {
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.fullScreen = true;
    }
}

This worked for me in a bare bones UI with a video URL set in the Load() event of the form.

Worked as expected, I must thank you alot, I have been stragling with this issue for a week. Thank very much.
